# Best practices to display calculated properties in 3 tiers architechure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, design-patterns, mvvm

In 3 tiers architecture, I have a customer order form with a grid, that shows a list of items to be added to another grid that represent the order items.

one of the columns in the items grid shows the last time the customer ordered this item if he did.
now I have the following code

```
public class Order {
   List<Items> items {get;set;}
   }

public class Item {
  int Id {get;set;}
  string Name {get;set;}
}
```

and as far as I know the model shouldn't be changed, so I can't add a property to Item class called LastOrderedDate.

and if not, how I'm going to display it (from best-practices point of view) in the grid without breaking the architecture ?
is it the MVVM pattern what I need ?

### [image: prototype to clearify the idea]

### Clarification:

when the selected customer in the combo changes, the LastOrderedDate column should also change its data.

Answer (score 1):

> as far as I know the model shouldn't be changed, so I can't add a
>   property to Item class called LastOrderedDate

Why? This is precisely what I would do. If the view requires another piece of information than you should add it to the model so it can be passed to the view.

If for some reasons you cannot modify `Item` class than you can create a wrapper class:

```
class ItemModel
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastOrderedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: actually the LastOrderDate is not related to the model, it is related to presentation layer, because it is used only in the view, and it is related to the current customer selected in the view and always changes when the selected customer changes, and it will not be persisted in database.

Comment: It doesn't matter that it's not persisted. If the view needs it in must be in the model class. Don't confuse the model for the view with the *model* of your database. Those are two different things.

Comment: exactly (Don't confuse the model for the view with the model of your database), the problem here that I'm using the same model for both, so I guess I need to create another model for the view?

Comment: Depends on what ORM tool you're using. You may be able to create a partial class or add another property to your db entity. Otherwise create another class for your model and use `AutoMapper` to simplify property copying.

Comment: Actually the ORM doesn't matter, because I'm not dealing with it directly, but using an interface with BLL, and AutoMapper doesn't solve the problem, because one of the properties can't be just copied simply, instead it should be queried from database ,passing the customer id related to current order.

Comment: I think you should re-architecture your application using MVVM / MVC patters - it will help you in long run.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually MVVM is what you need but you can wrap your Order/Item class in a MyOrderModel that contain LastOrderDate with Items last time added.

MVVM is actually best suited for WPF/Silverlight applications because they can utilize DataBinding/Commanding and a loosely coupled view and viewmodel. MVP is more likely to apply on winforms. check this http://sureshkumarveluswamy.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/mvvm-or-mvp-for-winforms/

Hope this will help.

Comment: I know MVVM is design pattern that contains more than just wrapping the model, but for knowledge-sake, is it good idea to use it in windows forms?? and considering MyOrderModel you suggested, can this class query the database for the information ??

Comment: No Models should not contain interaction logic with DAL they can only contain validation and relations to other models. if you already have not used any design pattern on your application i think its good to use MVVM/MVP depending on what makes you more comfortable.